# How to retrieve fabric unique run script number

Tags: crashlytics

i am new to using fabric.. i understand when you registered a new app, the fabric gives you something like this.

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run" API_KEY BUILD_SECRET
```

I have accidentally forgot the number, anyone knows where how i can retrieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. I edited your post to remove your keys, you can find you key and secret by visiting your [organization’s settings page](https://www.fabric.io/settings/organizations) and clicking on the respective links under the organization’s name.

Comment: It's still in the history though. I'll flag the mods.